# How to browse the internet while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, system-installation

During the installation of **Ubuntu 14.04** final beta release on **VirtualBox**. I was prompted with the option of reading the release notes. Being so curious about what difference does **14.04** make compared to **13.10**, I chose to read the release notes and **Firefox** popped up.

[image]

Other than the opened page was just [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com) and no the release notes page, I found that I can actually browse other websites too, which I consider could be extremely helpful in some situations.

So how can I open **Firefox** during **Ubuntu** installation ?  I can't rely on the installation to have a link to release notes in the first step, so I can open Firefox through it. I'm asking if there is a generic way to do this.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer is just a program. It's not really any different from opening Firefox while having other programs open.

Comment: @Nattgew, my question is, how can I open firefox while installing Ubuntu ? I'm not saying its impossible.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: I don't know how :) I can't rely on having a link for release notes with installations for every version. I event want to be able to do it with 12.04 or 13.10 or whatever version I'm installing. At least the latest ones.

Comment: Is the launcher on the left hidden during install?

Comment: Also try `Alt+F2` to try running a command.

Comment: The screenshot isn't cropped, it's a the full screen.

Comment: @Nattgew, I don't think its possible. I tried `Alt+F4` and I was prompted if I wan't to quit the installer, so `Alt`+ function keys are sent to the virtual machine. But `Alt+F2` isn't doing anything.

Comment: I guess the installer locks you out unless you start Ubuntu like in Luis's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to open Firefox (or even install apps) while doing the installer the first part is to select the **Try Ubuntu** option found as the first option in the installer:

[image]

The difference between both is that **Install Ubuntu** will automatically start the Ubuntu installer process. The **Try Ubuntu** will load the Desktop and you can play around with Ubuntu, including Firefox and if you are satisfied with Ubuntu on your PC you can proceed and click on the **Install Ubuntu** icon on the Desktop.

With this approach, even while you are installing Ubuntu, you will be able to do other things (Like browsing). This is by far the easiest most direct way to do what you want.

Comment: I think this is the only way.. :)

Comment: I guess this is the only way :(